# jQuery Ajax showing 0 instead of Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm trying pushing json inside of array, but when i send the params with Ajax it put 0 instead of Array...

Not really sure how do i get rid of it..
If anyone have any idea how to fix that I'll really appreciate it!

```
  var $selector = $(this).find('.button-selector');
  var $element = $(this).find('.button-type');
  var $attr = $(this).find('.selector ul li.active').attr('type');

  var $text = $(this).find('textarea').val();
  var $buttons = [];

  $selector.each(function(){
    var $titleBtn = $(this).find('input[name=button-title]').val();

    if($attr == 'block'){
      var $payload = "";

      var $value = $element.find('.block-select select').val();
      if($value == 1) {
        $payload = "JOIN_CONVERSATION_"+story_id+"";
      } else if ($value == 2) {
        $payload = "NEXT_BITE_"+story_id+"";
      } else if ($value == 3) {
        $payload = "INSTANT_ARTICLE_"+story_id+"";
      }

      button = {
        "type": "postback",
        "title": $titleBtn,
        "payload": $payload
      };

      $buttons.push(button)

    } else if($attr == 'url') {
      var $url = $element.find('.url-select input[type=url]').val();
      var $webView = $element.find('.url-select select').val();

      button = {
        "type": "web_url",
        "url": $url,
        "title": $titleBtn,
        "webview_height_ratio": $webView
      };

      $buttons.push(button)
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/variable',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      "element":{
        "notification_type": notification_type,
        "message": {
          "attachment": {
           "type": "template",
           "payload": {
             "template_type": "button",
             "text": $text,
             "buttons": $buttons
           }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

The output for buttons is:

```
"buttons"=>{"0"=>{"type"=>"postback", "title"=>"rwerwe", "payload"=>"JOIN_CONVERSATION_256"}}
```

Intead of:

```
"buttons"=>[{"type"=>"postback", "title"=>"rwerwe", "payload"=>"JOIN_CONVERSATION_256"}]
```

Comment: Just a note, you should really only use `$` as a prefix for variables if they are a JQuery object/array. This is unrelated to any issues, just a suggestion for you moving forward.

Comment: You don't need to change that. You can still access buttons[0] right? and you can loop into it also just like a regular array... even if it looks like an object.

Comment: What is the `$buttons` value before the `ajax` call?

Comment: @Santi: Alright, thanks for the note i keep it on mind..
@barudo: The problem is, im sending it out, it's not accepting it like that
@Aruna: Not sure what u mean.. its a variable and its `$buttons` (array)

Comment: @LiborZahrádka Just above the `$.ajax({` line, if you print `console.log($buttons)`, is it the same with `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this should fix your case.

You need to use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to first properly serialize your object to JSON, and then specify the `contentType: "application/json"` so your server understands it's JSON and deserialize it back. This should do the trick:

```
var jsonData = {
      "element":{
        "notification_type": notification_type,
        "message": {
          "attachment": {
           "type": "template",
           "payload": {
             "template_type": "button",
             "text": $text,
             "buttons": $buttons
           }
          }
        }
      }
    };

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/variable',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
  });
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't mentioned but i tried that and the problem is that its returning different JSON structure 
`"buttons"=>"[{\"type\":\"postback\",\"title\":\"rwerwe\",\"payload\":\"JOIN_CONVERSATION_256\"}]"` intead of `"buttons"=>[{"type"=>"postback", "title"=>"rwerwe", "payload"=>"JOIN_CONVERSATION_256"}]`

Comment: Yes, that's the serialized json string, you can check this in your server and should be deserialized back correctly.

Comment: Not sure, but when i send it to API its not responding so i can't use that structure

Comment: Which API it is, third party or your own API? Otherwise try this without `JSON.stringify` as `data: jsonData` but with `contentType: 'application/json'`.

Comment: its facebook and when i use `contentType: 'application/json'` im getting error 400 bad request

Comment: I believe the answer is correct but FaceBook is not accepting it due to Cross domain post. You have to check their `CORS` documentation.

Comment: When i use `JSON.stringify()` and print out to console. i get it right but once when i send it out there are 2 different structures `{"element"=>{"notification_type"=>"PUSH", "message"=>{"attachment"=>{"type"=>"template", "payload"=>{"template_type"=>"button", "text"=>"qweqe", "buttons"=>"[{\"type\":\"postback\",\"title\":\"rewrwer\",\"payload\":\"JOIN_CONVERSATION_256\"}]"}}}}}`

Comment: It's not two different structures, that's how console.log will work. The structure you placed above is correct, thats the serialized json string and how it should pass in a wire to the server. Don't worry about this. You have to check whether your api allows to post cross domain post request. I am not sure which api url you are using..

Comment: May I also check, how you did the `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: Im not using `console.log` for that it's in server log as params..
And i were right i used `JSON.stringify()` just for `$buttons` now im getting right params thanks a lot man! My bad..

Comment: Great you got it :-)